# docx "File is corrupt" error in Microsoft Word

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, docx

I wrote a program, which open docx package and changes some `<w:t>`-text in "word/document.xml". When i open new generated docx in Microsoft word, it gives me an error — "file is corrupted". But if look in "Open XML SDK Tool" diffs between template docx and result docx files — there is only two line changed in "word/document.xml". Look at screenshot:

[image]

Program doesn't touches document format, styles or smth. Only text in `<w:t>`

So, what's can provoke "file is corrupted" error in Microsoft Word?

And this error appears ONLY in Microsoft Word. For example OpenOffice and TextEdit on Mac OS X open generated files without any errors.

I upload [these](http://www.vanyamikhailov.ru/files/docxfiles.zip) docx files, so you can look at them by yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd make a blind guess and say that the document you modified contains UNIX-style line endings. Word 2003 does not tolerate a `\n` line ending, it requires `\r\n`  whereas Word 2007/2010 is more tolerant and accepts both versions.

Make sure to only use `\r\n` when modifying the document.

Update: I checked your document, and indeed the document XML part uses a UNIX-style line ending.

Update 2: You have an additional file included in your result document: `.DS_Store`. Remove that from the archive and the document will open.

Comment: Microsoft Office 2010 gives same error with "result.docx" — "file is corrupted". Also, i fixed UNIX-style line endings in document.xml with `unix2dos` command-line utility, and still no luck, same error appears.
Any ideas?

Comment: Notice. Word 2007 doesn't accept `\n` line ending in `pkg:binaryData` element, while Word 2010 does.