# removing paragraph tag from word document causes corruption only for microsoft word

Tags: c, docx, libxml2

I'm using libxml2 and libzip to open and edit a word document in C. It mostly works. when I remove a run or a paragraph from the word document using libxml's unlink and free node functions microsoft word can't open the file and claims that it's corrupted, however other programs like libreoffice, for example can open it. For example this is what the `document.xml` looks like before and after the removal.

after:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00EB2661" w:rsidRPr="002D26CA" w:rsidRDefault="00EB2661" w:rsidP="00EB2661">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
      <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
</w:p>
```

before:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00EB2661" w:rsidRPr="002D26CA" w:rsidRDefault="00EB2661" w:rsidP="00EB2661">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Heading1"/>
    <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
      <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r w:rsidRPr="002D26CA">
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
      <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">INHERENCY</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="00EB2661" w:rsidRPr="002D26CA" w:rsidRDefault="00EB2661" w:rsidP="00EB2661">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
      <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
</w:p>
```

And as a side note, opening the document in libreoffice and then saving it without modifying anything allows microsoft word to open it.

libreoffice modified the document by changing the `document` tag from

```
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se wp14">
```

to:

```
<w:document xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" mc:Ignorable="w14 wp14">
```

there's also a couple tags before the main content of the document that libreoffice changes.
from:

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00EB2661" w:rsidRPr="002D26CA" w:rsidRDefault="00EB2661" w:rsidP="00EB2661">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Title"/>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
      <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
  <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/>
</w:p>
<w:p w:rsidR="00EB2661" w:rsidRPr="002D26CA" w:rsidRDefault="00EB2661" w:rsidP="00EB2661">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:spacing w:line="240" w:lineRule="auto"/>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
      <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
      <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:pict>
      <v:rect id="_x0000_i1025" style="width:0;height:1.5pt" o:hrstd="t" o:hr="t" fillcolor="#a0a0a0" stroked="f"/>
    </w:pict>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"/>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

to:

```
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Title"/>
    <w:spacing w:before="240" w:after="120"/>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
      <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial"/>
      <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve"/>
  </w:r>
  <w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/>
  <w:bookmarkStart w:id="1" w:name="_GoBack"/>
  <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="1"/>
</w:p>
<w:p>
  <w:pPr>
    <w:pStyle w:val="Normal"/>
    <w:spacing w:lineRule="auto" w:line="240"/>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:hAnsi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
      <w:color w:val="000000" w:themeColor="text1"/>
    </w:rPr>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr/>
    <mc:AlternateContent>
      <mc:Choice Requires="wps">
        <w:drawing>
          <wp:inline distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0">
            <wp:extent cx="5944235" cy="19685"/>
            <wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"/>
            <wp:docPr id="1" name=""/>
            <a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main">
              <a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
                <wps:wsp>
                  <wps:cNvSpPr/>
                  <wps:nvSpPr>
                    <wps:cNvPr id="0" name="Rectangle 1"/>
                    <wps:cNvSpPr/>
                  </wps:nvSpPr>
                  <wps:spPr>
                    <a:xfrm>
                      <a:off x="0" y="0"/>
                      <a:ext cx="5943600" cy="19080"/>
                    </a:xfrm>
                    <a:prstGeom prst="rect">
                      <a:avLst/>
                    </a:prstGeom>
                    <a:solidFill>
                      <a:srgbClr val="a0a0a0"/>
                    </a:solidFill>
                    <a:ln>
                      <a:noFill/>
                    </a:ln>
                  </wps:spPr>
                  <wps:bodyPr/>
                </wps:wsp>
              </a:graphicData>
            </a:graphic>
            <wp14:sizeRelH relativeFrom="page">
              <wp14:pctWidth>100000</wp14:pctWidth>
            </wp14:sizeRelH>
          </wp:inline>
        </w:drawing>
      </mc:Choice>
      <mc:Fallback>
        <w:pict>
          <v:rect id="shape_0" fillcolor="#a0a0a0" stroked="f" style="position:absolute;margin-left:0pt;margin-top:-1.55pt;width:467.95pt;height:1.45pt;mso-position-horizontal:left;mso-position-vertical:top">
            <w10:wrap type="none"/>
            <v:fill o:detectmouseclick="t" type="solid" color2="#5f5f5f"/>
            <v:stroke color="#3465a4" joinstyle="round" endcap="flat"/>
          </v:rect>
        </w:pict>
      </mc:Fallback>
    </mc:AlternateContent>
    <w:t xml:space="preserve">100000</w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

other than that i've noticed no other changes

original unedited file: https://pastebin.com/pd1Cx97D

file edited by my c program: https://pastebin.com/MBABRV1w

previous file after getting opened and saved libre office with no modifications: https://pastebin.com/9t4vcXm5

Comment: Ok, so what are the differences between the input to libreoffice and the output?

Comment: @user3386109 i've edited the main post because the changes were too big to describe in a comment

Comment: Thank you for the response but I seem to be struggling to understand what that attribute is exactly. I should also point out that every single run seems to have that exact same attribute with the exact same value, and every single paragraph seems to begin with the exact same line as shown in the for the first line of `after`

Comment: @user3386109 I just wanted to say that after researching this for a bit it seems that rsidRPr is just a way to track in what session an edit was made to the document, this isn't a tag to refer to the paragraph/run removed but rather to help merged documents that are edited. from what I see removing it shouldn't break a document.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions from [docx “File is corrupt” error in Microsoft Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3547007/docx-file-is-corrupt-error-in-microsoft-word)?

Comment: @nwellnhof the program was tested on both a windows and linux machine so that couldn't possibly be the issue since that would make it work on the windows machine. Plus the version of office im using according to that post would support either line ending. In either case it wouldn't matter much because the xml file doesn't actually have any newline characters, all the tags are on one line. I simply modified it for the purpose of posting it here so that it's easily readable